# How to arrange a special table format of List of DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

For example, I have list of `DateTime` like this;

```
List<DateTime> timeList;
```

I use repeater to creat a table like below;

```
YEAR    MONTH           DATES
2012    SEPTEMBER   08  15  22  29
2012    OCTOBER     06  20  27   
2012    NOVEMBER    10           
2012    DECEMBER    08           
2013    MAY         04  18       
2013    JUNE        01  15  29   
2013    JULY        13  27       
2013    AUGUST      10  24       
2013    SEPTEMBER   07  21       
2013    OCTOBER     05  19
```

But I am unable to group dates. How can I achieve this using repeater?

Comment: What data type are you using to bind to the Repeater? You note a list of dates per a year/month. Where/how does that get populated?

Comment: Can you put a sample of how the output will look like after grouping.

Comment: @roughnex The table in the question is output table. so I mean, I want to group dates by month.

Comment: @gunr2171 I cannot bind List of DateTime to repeater because of I dont know how to bind like above.

Comment: @MehmetInce, ok, so I ask again. What datatype are you trying to bind to your repeater? Also, how do you know which dates go to which year/month? Like: "08, 15, 22, 29 go to 2012-Sep"?

Comment: My solution is to creat a class which holds Year, Month and 4 days of Month. But I couldnt group List of DateTime.

Comment: How do you know which "4 days" go to a Year and Month?

Comment: Dude, in my implementation, User selects 4 days from a month.

Comment: @MehmetInce, sorry about my impatience. It took be a bit to realize how your data was formatted. But I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make a class which will hold your data:

```
public class DateInfo
{       
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Days { get; set; }

    public string DisplayDayList
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(" ", Days.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray()); //sorry, i'm doing .net 3.5
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can group by Year/Month to get your list to bind.

```
List<DateTime> dtList = new List<DateTime>();
List<DateInfo> dateInfoList = 
    (from dt in dtList
     group dt by new { dt.Year, dt.Month } into g
     select new DateInfo()
     {
         Year = g.Key.Year,
         Month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(g.Key.Month),
         Days = g.Select(x => x.Day)
     }).ToList();
```

Now, bind using your new list object, and only bind the `Year`, `Month`, and `DisplayDayList` columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can group by using this query

```
var query = from t in timeList
            group t by new { t.Year, t.Month } into g
            select new { Month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(g.Key.Month), 
            Year = g.Key.Year, 
            Dates = g.Select(t => t.Day) };
```